# Paypal Recurring billing - pro? standard?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am setting up a site where users can subscribe on a yearly basis.
I have it complete through the payment pro api but completely missed the charges.
If i understand it correctly, its £20 a month for pro and £20 a month for repeat billing.
Is this correct?

To create a subscription site, is paypal pro my only option ? does paypal offer other, cheaper options?

Really confused with their site and information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PayPal Website Payments Standard and use subscription buttons.  There is no monthly charge for this service.  The only charge would be a transaction fee for each transaction or subscription charge.

Comment: How do users cancel subscriptions?

Comment: Here’s how to cancel a subscription or recurring payment:

1.Log in to your PayPal account.
2.Click Profile near the top of the page.
3.Select My money.
4.In the My preapproved payments section, click Update.
5.Select the merchant whose agreement you want to cancel and click Cancel.
6.Click 'Cancel Profile’ to confirm your request.

Comment: Ah, so the customer would need to get in touch and we would need to manually cancel the subscription.

Comment: Well there are 3 different ways you can cancel the subscription.  The buyer can cancel it from their PayPal account, you as the merchant can cancel it from your PayPal account, or you could use an API call to cancel the subscription.  Along with the API, you could create a GUI type of interface and allow the buyer to come to your site and put in their information and cancel it or automate it in some other way using the API call.

Comment: I assume the api approach is pp pro only?

Comment: No, you can use it with your business or premiere PayPal account.  It does not need to have pro enabled on it to be able to use the API to cancel a profile.

Comment: I have a standard business account, does that mean I can use the api to create/cancel subscriptions?

Comment: Yes and No.  You can't use the API to create a recurring payment where the buyer pays with a credit card without adding on an additional service to your account at a cost of a monthly charge.  However you can use the API to create recurring payments where the buyer pays with their PayPal account, which could be tied to a credit card.  There is no charge for this, and you can also use the API to cancel a profile for Express Checkout, or for Website Payments Standard subscriptions.